# How to make swipe on horizontal recyclerview bring only the next item into view - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` that shows 4 `cards` numbered 1-4. These cards take up the entire width of the screen so only 1 card can be fully visible at a time. The user is presented with the first card, when they swipe the card to the left like this,

[image]

the `RecyclerView` will scroll all the way to number 4. **I don't want that.**

**I want the swipe to bring the next card (number 2) into the view**

Similar to how Androids `ViewPager` works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Added in android.support library

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!