# An instance of OnFlingListener already set in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView in my Android app. I've many cardviews in my RecyclerView, such that only 1 cardview is displayed to the user at a time. The user has to swipe to see the next card.

I faced an issue that when user makes a swipe, the recyclerview gets scrolled to the end. Instead, what I need is when the user swipes, display the next card to the user as mentioned in this post.

[How to make swipe on horizontal recyclerview bring only the next item into view - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778461/how-to-make-swipe-on-horizontal-recyclerview-bring-only-the-next-item-into-view)

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

I tried the answer mentioned in the above link. But I'm getting an exception when the user makes a swipe.

Please help me resolve it.

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An instance of OnFlingListener already set.
    at android.support.v7.widget.SnapHelper.setupCallbacks(SnapHelper.java:114)
    at android.support.v7.widget.SnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(SnapHelper.java:102)
    at com.abc.ui.trm.TrCard.setupCardView(TrCard.java:62)
    at com.abc.ui.trm.TrCard.setupCardView(TrCard.java:29)
    at com.abc.ui.core.card.BaseCardView.processCardView(BaseCardView.java:134)
    at com.abc.ui.card.CardRecyclerAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(CardRecyclerAdapter.java:398)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:6758)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:696)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:7697)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7655)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7643)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1539)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1488)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3506)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3254)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3767)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at com.abc.ui.core.refresh.LegacySwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(LegacySwipeRefreshLayout.java:337)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:822)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18799)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5952)
```

Comment: Does this help any? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370289/snappy-scrolling-in-recyclerview

Comment: See its second answer and comment to it as well. :)

Answer (score 106):

I managed to sovle this with adding this line

```
recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
```

before

```
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: easy and simple solution. It might be a hacky solution, but as far as I see the complicated implementation of SnapHelper, it´s the best solution and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Adding both clearOnScrollListeners() and  setOnFlingListener(null) solved my problem

Comment: I got this error if I set the data again to recycler view, adding `setOnFlingListener` effected the `recyclerView.addOnScrollListener`. it wasn't triggering after data set second time. So I called my fragment again by setting arguments to it.

Comment: @NoumanCh Have you already resolved your issue? And do you have an addition to how you solved it for us?

Comment: @RikvanVelzen yes, I had resolved it through some ways I don't remember now.

Answer (score 31):

You can check for OnFlingListener on the RecyclerView first before you add it

```
if (recycler.getOnFlingListener() == null)
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler);
```

Answer (score 10):

**All you have to do is place**

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

inside **onCreateViewHolder** instead of **onBindViewHolder**

Answer (score 9):

This happens because you're setting the `SnapPagerHelper` twice somehow. Note that if you have a `RecyclerView` inside another `RecyclerView`, this should only happen in each other's constructors or Kotlin's `init {}` block (once per item).
My case is quite similar to yours since I have a big vertical `RecyclerView` and a small `RecyclerView` within.

Code that will cause the exception:

```
 fun bind(value: ArrayList<Item>) {
    listAdapter = ItemCellDelegate(value)

    val manager = LinearLayoutManager(itemView.context)
    manager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL

    horizontalRecyclerView?.apply {
        layoutManager = manager
        adapter = listAdapter
        setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    val snapHelper: SnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(horizontalRecyclerView)

}
```

Correct code using `init {}` block:

```
init {
    val snapHelper: SnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(horizontalRecyclerView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
override fun onAttachedToWindow(view: RecyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToWindow(view)
    view.onFlingListener = null;
    StartSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also getting Error in neasted RecyclerView or inner RecyclerView,
I managed to sovle this with adding this line.

```
holder.rv_sub_loaction.setOnFlingListener(null);
```

Whole recyclerView set code:

```
subLocationModels.addAll(response.body());
            recyclerDataAdapter = new SubSubLocationAdapter(subLocationModels);
            SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new  GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            holder.rv_sub_loaction.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            holder.rv_sub_loaction.setOnFlingListener(null);
            holder.rv_sub_loaction.setAdapter(recyclerDataAdapter);
            helper.attachToRecyclerView(holder.rv_sub_loaction);
            holder.rv_sub_loaction.setHasFixedSize(true);
```